# geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, file, ssl-certificate, geopy, geocoder

I was recently using geopy and when I tried to use the geocoder part of it, it gave me the error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 948, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1422, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py", line 251, in get_text
    page = self.urlopen(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/syedrishad/Downloads/Code/python_basics/basics.py", line 8, in <module>
    n= nom.geocode("3995 23rd St, San Francisco, CA 94114")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/arcgis.py", line 173, in geocode
    return self._authenticated_call_geocoder(url, callback, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/arcgis.py", line 260, in _authenticated_call_geocoder
    return self._call_geocoder(url, parse_callback, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/base.py", line 360, in _call_geocoder
    result = self.adapter.get_json(url, timeout=timeout, headers=req_headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py", line 240, in get_json
    text = self.get_text(url, timeout=timeout, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopy/adapters.py", line 268, in get_text
    raise GeocoderServiceError(message)
geopy.exc.GeocoderServiceError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
```

I searched this error up, and apparently, all I had to do was go to my python folder and double click on the "Install Certificates.command" file. Except for one thing. I'm on Mac which means I had to download Python using the `brew install python3` command. I can't find the Python folder anywhere which means that I can't double click on the "Install Certificates.command" file. Does anybody have any advice on what I can do. Any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Updating all packages helped me on windows.

Update All Python Packages On Windows
The easiest way to update all packages in a Windows environment is to use pip in conjunction with Windows PowerShell:

1. Open a command shell by typing ‘powershell’ in the Search Box of the Task bar
2. Enter:
   `pip freeze | %{$_.split('==')[0]} | %{pip install --upgrade $_}`